# Scala-Dispatch | Log into web site programmably

Tags: scala, scala-dispatch

I'm still fighting with programmatically logging in to one site, My code:

```
val h = new Http 
val req = url("http://www.smanager.pl/logowanie.php") << 
    Map("username" -> "MYUSERNAME", "password" -> "MYPASSWORD") 
val handler = req.POST >>> System.out print(h(handler))
```

Username and password are correct for sure in the script, but on `system.out` I see the html of the login form. It doesn't work. Any have idea how to deal with it?

Comment: The page probably checks if you are already logged in with the help of cookies. Are you sure your http library supports them?

Comment: No Im not, i dont know dispatch good. Ive done smth like it in C# and webclient and it logged ok, but i want to code it in scala..

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to login, or at least to dump requests, using curl? Maybe you need to additionally specify authentication type, for example Digest